# login_urlをつけているのにログインサイトに遷移しない　Django

Tags: python, django, social-framework

Django1.6とdjango-social-authを使用しています。

login_requiredをviews.pyではなく、
urls.pyに記載して、

```
url(r'^hoge/$',
    login_required(hoge_view),
    name='paypal'),
```

をしていますが、何故かログインのページに遷移しません。

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```

も設定しています。

ご教示よろしくお願い致します。